# Javascript onkeydown event fires only once

Tags: javascript

My onkeydown function fires only once but I however want it to fire every time a key is pressed. The div object should move in a continuous motion on pressing the arrow keys.

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
      #Rectangle{
        height:40px;
        width:40px;
        background-color:red;   
        position:absolute;   
    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        var box = document.getElementById("Rectangle");
        document.onkeydown = function(e){
            e = e || window.event;
            switch(e.which){
                case 38: //down
                box.style.top -= 10;
                break;

                case 40: //up
                box.style.top += 10;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

<body onload="start()">
    <div id="Rectangle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure, `onload` is just in one moment, when `body` is loaded.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mtbfxh1b/ *(click on the square to make that iframe your target before hitting keys)*

Comment: I think that the += 10 should not work because you need to add px at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needing to prevent NaN result of parseInt():

```
case 38: //down
  box.style.top = ((parseInt(box.style.top, 10) || 0) - 10) + 'px';
  break;

case 40: //up
  box.style.top = ((parseInt(box.style.top, 10) || 0) + 10) + 'px';
  break;
```

Answer (score 2):

top has units, your Math is wrong

```
case 38: //down
    box.style.top = ( parseInt(box.style.top, 10) - 10 ) + "px";
    break;

case 40: //up
    box.style.top = ( parseInt(box.style.top, 10) + 10 ) + "px";
    break;
```

Comment: can you explain to OP why you have to convert the string to an integer, and why you append the "px"? Might help him.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
I didn get you have a js error, so you need to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    var box = document.getElementById("Rectangle"), func = function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        var top = parseInt(box.style.top);
        switch(e.which){
            case 38: //down
            box.style.top = (top - 10) + "px";
            break;

            case 40: //up
            box.style.top = (top + 10) + "px";
            break;
        }
    };
    document.onkeyup = func(e);
}
</script>
```

Comment: removed my downvote for further effort, but can you actually explain to OP what you are doing, instead of just providing a chunk of code?

Answer (score -3):

try this

```js
document.onkeypress = function() {
   
  //insert your code here
  alert("key pressed!");
 };
```